# How to share records structure between projects, with slight variations?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe7

I have 2 projects that work on same data, different processes. Main arrays are almost identical with slight variations, like:

```
// Project 1

TData1 = record
  A:string;
  B:integer;
  C:word;
  ...
end;

// Project 2

TData1 = record
  A:string;
  B:integer;
  C:word;
  ...
  XMLNode:TXMLNode; // Extra value needed in Project 2, not needed in Project 1
end;
```

I have numerous arrays that i want to share between projects. I would like to keep the same array structure so I can copy&paste any future changes that need to be implemented in both projects. 
Is there any way to keep records same with slight difference?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
    // in Project 1:

    TExtras = record
    end;

    // in Project 2:

    TExtras = record
      XMLNode:TXMLNode;
    end;

    // shared - in both projects

    TData1 = record
      A:string;
      B:integer;
      C:word;
      ...
      Extras:TExtras; // different extra fields based on project needs
    end;
```

And i can add additional fields into Extras in Project2 accessing fields with `Data1.Extras.XMLNode`. Not sure if this is future proof implementation.

The goal is to one day put all the shared structure into shared unit, one maintenance point and no more copy&paste. I need arrays to retain flexibility as simple arrays (`array of TData1` or `TArray<TData1>`), so I can't go into complex implementation that will limit option to easily copy, sort, make distinct, manipulate data...

**Is that correct approach? Any better ideas?**

---

**Edit:**

Both projects work on same data, so they both read from the same 'source' files, but produce different end results. Right now I have lots of arrays and 99% of them are used for the same purpose in both projects, same functions.
But now, when I work on one or the other project, adding new record fields, new functions that use new fields, and if I don't immediately synchronize the structure and new functions, it happens that in a few weeks I will need to to do the same in project 2 and I will create new fields with different names and different function names. So, when I finally copy some complex function between projects, I see they don't match only due to different naming.

---

**Edit 2:**

From all the comments and suggestions I have decided to go another route: to share common data structure and code in shared unit and create additional arrays with extra record fields in project 2. I would create these new arrays that link to main data arrays, to have:

```
// shared data 
TData1 = record
  A:string;
  B:integer;
  C:word;
  ...
end;

Data1:TArray<TData1>;

// additional in Project 2
TDataExtra = record
  DataIdx:integer;// link to TData1
  XMLNode:TXMLNode;
  ...
end; 

DataExtras:TArray<TDataExtra>;
```

to have simple access to XMLNode value for each Data1 record:

```
fGetXMLNode(i); // where i is index in Data1 array and function will return XMLNode
```

I believe with this I can keep shared units and add any extras to any array, with the minimal extra work, which is still lower cost than maintaining 2 data structure and code.

**Would that be better solution?**

Comment: Sounds like you are doing wrong. I wouldn't want to advise you on how to do it right, without proper context. But this smells very bad.

Comment: I can provide more context. Any specifics, so I get to the point?

Comment: I have the feeling that you have loads of different projects with masses of duplicated code. Untangling that will be a total nightmare. If you have two types with different members, then surely they should no considered to be the same type. What you'll get now though is every man and his dog suggesting solutions, when nobody really understands the problem.

Comment: Your edit provides yet more evidence that you are going about this entirely the wrong way

Comment: Been there, done that. Project consisted of EXE and set of DLLs, data exchange was made using records and procedures copied from one unit to another, and assumption (no enforcement) that all the relevant compiler options would be the same. When DLLs needed to exchange data they cloned those records, then added 2-3 extra fields they needed to exchange, and also copied the supporting procedures. Scaffoldingg also included C-style flags like `const request_mode_a = 1; request_mode_b = 2; request_mode_c = 4; ....` and `record ... Flags: word; ... ExtraFlags: byte;... end`.

Comment: With years that all was diverging out of sync, to the point when module X only correctly worked provided zzz.DLL build 2006-2009 and module Y required the very same zzz.DLL but of builds 2011 or newer. And since there was no clear abstract interface, updating X to zzz.DLL 2011+ took finding newer support routines in the spaghetti, separation scaffolding from business logic, finding flag constant with different semantics but same values, understanding algorithms in module X and adapting them to changed datatypes and expectations of zzz.DLL 2011+, etc... It was quite a journey

Comment: Extra present was when fields like `Unused: pointer`, `Reserved: integer`, `MemoryPadding: array[1..3] of byte` were actually sometimes used to pass the data depending upon flags. Lost pointer and AV ? nothing special...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Correct, lots of duplicated code and I take a day for these changes here and there, among new development. So, not an option for complete change of code, but I can do some cleaning up. Not the best, but the code is already getting much better ever since i started using SO. Now I have this challenge, how to prevent 2 projects to go into different direction, into maintenance nightmare. I thought shared unit for data structure would help.

Comment: @Arioch'The As you said you have gone through something similar, what do you think of my proposed solution in Edit 2? To have extra data arrays, with links to main data and only use them where needed, and keep shared data structure unchanged across projects. This is doable for me in regards of time and my experience (what I can really do effectively in allowed time)

Comment: We have different problems, not the amount of data, but protocols across modules and random problems after every upgrade, different with different clients.  "To have extra data arrays, with links to main data" implies you would be easy to go from those extra-info subsets to the main, but not vice versa. So depends upon what would you traverse through. Depends upon requirements. Case 1: Module X only works with data having extra frame A skips the rest, Module Y only works with data with B frames. Then you make looong base array (or other container) with basic data. and array of A with ptrs

Comment: ...to base, and another short array of B with links to base. Then you only pass those short arrays to Modules X and Y as they do not need the data lacking those extra frames. That might work. However! Imagine Module Y might use services of Module X. Module Y calls Module X API and passes there pointers to the B frame and to the base array item. Module Y just has nothing else. Not Module X discards the B frame (it does not need it) and would require pointers to the A-frame and to the base. The latter it gets from the Y. But how to check/find A-frame for the given base ptr????

Comment: I think you are to start reading upon different data containers and their cons and pros. Maybe look into Spring4D library, maybe read about Scala RTL ( not applicable to Delphi, but they focus on different collection as a backbone of what they see applications design should be. Somewhat resembling famous Wirth's book title). "Arrays everywhere" might be not the best idea - they are fixed-size, traversing is ultra-fast, but re-sizing (inserting or deleting items for example) is very expensive

Comment: Maybe you should think about records identifiers instead of pointers, extra code, extra execution time, but you might push certain records back to disk and load them on demand, instead of overflowing Win32 memory space and risking AV in case of array resizing/moving in memory.  No silver bullet, no one size fits all, sorry

Comment: @Arioch'The Thank you for detailed answer, it reaffirms there's no easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy solution is to keep the data structure and related functions shared between both projects and add additional arrays that contain additional data, specific to each project. 
It will bring slightly more work to use extra arrays, but will keep shared code really shared.

So, instead of new classes or IFDefs, as proposed in other anwers, a simple extra arrays that link to main data are best option for the problem:

```
// shared main data through both projects
TData1 = record
  A:string;
  B:integer;
  C:word;
  ...
end;

Data1:TArray<TData1>;

// additional in Project 2
TDataExtra = record
  DataIdx:integer;// link to TData1
  XMLNode:TXMLNode;
  ...
end; 

DataExtras:TArray<TDataExtra>;
```

With this solution, any additional arrays, like DataExtras or any other extra fields for other arrays, are easy to add, expand, without needing to change shared code. Shared code will be easy to maintain, as it only holds main data and nothing specific to only one project

Answer (score 2):

It is going to be hard to say which solution would be best/better without the full context,  but here's a few other methods that can achieve the same.

**Conditional define**

```
TData1 = record
  A:string;
  B:integer;
  C:word;
  [...]
{$IFDEF NEEDXMLNODEINTDATA1}
  XMLNode:TXMLNode; // different extra fields based on project needs
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

**Use a new structure**

Use a different structure in your 2nd application. I would expect this to be the right approach for most cases.

```
TData1Node = record
  Data1 : TData1;
  XMLNode : TXMLNode;
end;
```

**Include XMLNode all the time**

Since it's just a pointer, unless you have an absurd amount of records in your application, it would barely register on memory usage.

Comment: Option 4: use classes, not records, and store the classes in the array. Classes can be polymorphic.Of course if you must take care of proper serialzation. Option 5: Use variant records, i.e. records with a `case` part. This means you must know which kind of "extras" you may need. Not very futrue proof, IMO.

Comment: Thank you. I do have a lot of data, so keeping unnecessary fields is not an option, right now. `{$IFDEF` is interesting.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In this case, variant records would be pointless. The idea of variant records is to save memory when a record only need some of its fields depending on its "type". It basically share memory between some fields. (Which is why you can't use "managed" type in the variant part of a record). Granted, it would become of interest in this context if a 3rd application required a TTreeNode instead of a TXMLNode, but it would still always require 4 extra bytes in the "base" application.

Comment: The question is about sharing slightly differing records. That is what variant records were designed for. The XLMNode is merely an example. The "extra" might just as well be something bigger than a pointer. Not very future proof, though.

Comment: @Rudy The real question is why you have types that you feel represent the same thing, but actually differ. Trying to shove everything into a single type may not be the best solution to the problem. Thing is, we can only guess at the problem. Which is what happens now.

Comment: Sure, we can only guess. But we can suggest the usual solutions. Polymorphism is one, variant records are another one. The latter is "poor man's polymophism", but may sometimes be a solution. The fact the suggestion with the conditional defines looked good means that something is indeed wrong here. If this is just to avoid code duplication, perhaps generics might help instead.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, if conditionals looks good to the asker, then something is wrong. Everything points to this not being a single type. Which is why I don't think it is helpful to offer single type solutions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that maybe is similar to how generics and mixins were born. The types that are different in memory layout, but similar in semantics/behavior. TArray<integer>, TArray<word> and TArray<double> are different data types, but many algorithms using them would be literally the same on sources level

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni how often do you really fill those `XMLNode : TXMLNode;` pointers? you say "keeping unnecessary fields is not an option" - but that slack is merely one byte per item (after for example `type TXMLNode=byte` compatibility stub in proj.2). More so, since you use memory-padded `record` instead of bytes-squeezing `packed record` you datatype might already have the unused spots, you can squeeze that extra member into while keeping the same `SizeOf*TData1)`, and your `C:word;` examples strongly hints at it.

Comment: At the same time the real TXMLNode object instance would occupy dozens if not hundreds byte each one. And you feel okay to spend as much per-record in Proj.1 and afraid to spend one extra byte in Proj.2 ??? I suspect that is something wrong with design, perhaps you could think about algorithms keeping most of data on-disk until needed

Comment: BTW, "Use a new structure" also can be amended by `class operator TData1Node.Implicit (const from: TData1Node): TData1;` and `class operator TData1Node.Implicit (const from: TData1): TData1Node;` to make legacy code reuse-by-copypaste easier

Comment: I like IFDEF option, since it doesn't involve changing any references to current arrays, fields, which I assume classes do. I was hoping for a simple (er) solution and it seems there is none, as it is a complex system and it's not to design new one, but changing existing one, 2 not small projects.

Comment: @Arioch'The XMLNode is an example to be able to ask the question, MCVE. Numerous arrays with 1 or 2 fields difference. 95% code shareable.

Comment: You don't seem to be embracing the real problem at all

Comment: I was hoping Edit would provide the context, I already maintain 2 different versions of very similar code - just thought there is a simple way to ease the process of maintenance.

Comment: The game is lost already. The code is not shared. Coupling the two variants makes matters even worse. Now you have no benefit from sharing since you don't share, but you pay the cost of the coupling. You aren't thinking straight at all.

Comment: Conditional compiling is poorman's generics. It adds new troubles, but it also gives some level of code reuse. For example he then can start refactoring that code piece by piece going away from current design to something more flexible and uniform. Without this kind of IfDef's it would take to repeat same refactorings over two codebases that both are moving targets, continuing slowly diverging due to everyday small changes. With topicstarter's approach he maybe would be able to localize the part being remodeled from the rest of the code and would make DRY refactorings.

Comment: That said, it would only be a temporary scaffolding, the aid for reconstruction on-the-run. I think the topicstarter really should start with determining his end goal, his new unified architecture that would be his final destination, and use IfDef's as ugly hacks helping to move there, not as a final solution.

Answer (score 2):

Pascal does not have void/Unit datatype, still you can kind of simulate it.
The compiler does not always feel nice about it, in some paths it just makes no assumption/check that in some extreme cases `SizeOf(someType)` might be zero.

Still, if you really need to squeeze every last byte in Project 2 while keeping sources shared with Project 1 there can be used this ugly hack:

File Project_1.inc

```
{$IFnDEF THIS_IS_PROJECT_1}
halt compilation! wrong setup!!!
{$EndIf}

{$IFDEF THIS_IS_PROJECT_2}
halt compilation! wrong setup!!!
{$EndIf}

type TDataPayload = TXMLNode;
```

File Project_2.inc

```
{$IFnDEF THIS_IS_PROJECT_2}
halt compilation! wrong setup!!!
{$EndIf}

{$IFDEF THIS_IS_PROJECT_1}
halt compilation! wrong setup!!!
{$EndIf}

type REmpty = packed record end;

type TDataPayload = REmpty;

// after compilation - call `assert(SizeOf(TDataPayload) = 0);`
```

File CommonDataType.pas

```
{$IfDef THIS_IS_PROJECT_1}
  {$INCLUDE Project_1.inc}
{$EndIf}

{$IfDef THIS_IS_PROJECT_2}
  {$INCLUDE Project_2.inc}
{$EndIf}

TData1 = 
{$IFDEF THIS_IS_PROJECT_2}
  packed
{$EndIf}
  record
    A:string;
    B:integer;
    C:word;
  ...
    Payload: TDataPayLoad;
  end;
```

That being said, your assessment that you can not waste a single byte via `type TXMLNode=byte` compatibility stub in the project 2 seems very dubious to me. Because:

1. you use fast memory-padded `record` instead of slow bytes-squeezing `packed record`
2. you use TXMLNode, even if in a different project - every TObject instance would occupy dozens of bytes anyway, pointers to RTTI, pointers to VMT, supporting frames in Heap Manager.... The very pointer to it in the record would additionally occupy 4 or 8 bytes. And you cannot afford just ONE extra byte instead of all that??? Come on!
3. Your very `A:string;` spends 4 (or 8) bytes per the pointer inside every record and then 12 bytes more as `StringRec` header, and then unknown pre-allocated just-in-case buffer after the string content, and then two extra bytes for trailing #0, and then supporting data structures in the Heap Manager. Still just ONE extra byte of `type TXMLNode=boolean` stub is way too much???
4. if your application performance/correctness is dependent upon just one extra byte per data frame, that also means that as the user would generate 5% more data than usual your application would break as well. Period. If to trust your assessment, then your application already hit the bar, already is past the algorithms/design limits. And should be remodeled to use memory-unbound algorithms. A simple example - instead of using in-memory Quicksort you could use on-disk Streaming Sort, it has the same worst-case complexity but does only need memory for 4 data frames.

Comment: The records are a bit longer than example, of course. And single XMLNode is also just an example, in  some cases it is, in some cases there are 2 additional integers or string fields (some arrays have 50+ fields). So, I would need to consider this in optimizing other parts to go with same records.

Comment: Well, it might work as an intermediate temporary method, but in the end you have to unify datatypes across all the modules, or your code would not become manageable. Same with fixed-format flat files - they are fragile. Better switch to at very least DBF-like structures, where record format is described in the header before the data, so the program modules could load different (while related) record-types from the same file. Better yet to consider upgrading storage to more universal back-ends, like SQL, JSON, XML/Binary or EBML, etc

Comment: if you have same subsets used time and again - try extracting them, into separate named chunks and then merging them together into wider records like @KenBourassa shown in his "Use a new structure" answer chapter